# How to do source filtering on Nested Fields

Tags: elasticsearch

**Sample document**

```
{
 "id" : "video1",
  "title" : "Gone with the wind",
  "timedTextLines" : [ 
    {
      "startTime" : "00:00:02",
      "endTime" :  "00:00:05",
      "textLine" : "Frankly my dear I don't give a damn."
    },
   {
      "startTime" : "00:00:07",
      "endTime" :  "00:00:09",
      "textLine" : " my amazing country."
    },
 {
      "startTime" : "00:00:17",
      "endTime" :  "00:00:29",
      "textLine" : " amazing country."
    }
  ]
}
```

**Index Definition**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "video_type": {
      "properties": {
        "timedTextLines": {
          "type": "nested" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response without source filtering in inner works fine.

```
{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.91737854,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "video_index",
        "_type": "video_type",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.91737854,
        "_source": {

        },
        "inner_hits": {
          "timedTextLines": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 1,
              "max_score": 0.6296964,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "timedTextLines",
                    "offset": 0
                  },
                  "_score": 0.6296964,
                  "_source": {
                    "startTime": "00:00:02",
                    "endTime": "00:00:05",
                    "textLine": "Frankly my dear I don't give a damn."
                  },
                  "highlight": {
                    "timedTextLines.textLine": [
                      "Frankly my dear I don't give a <em>damn</em>."
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Response contains all the properties for the nested property. viz startTime, endTime and textLine. How can I return just the endtime and startTime in the response?

**Failed query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "gone"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "timedTextLines",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "timedTextLines.textLine": "damn"
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {
             "_source":["startTime","endTime"],
              "highlight": {
                "fields": {
                  "timedTextLines.textLine": {

                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source":"false"
}
```

**Error**
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 265

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"[inner_hits]
>   _source doesn't support values of type: START_ARRAY"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"[inner_hits]
>   _source doesn't support values of type: START_ARRAY"},"status":400}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason is because since ES 5.0 the `_source` in `inner_hits` doesn't support the short form anymore, but only the full object form (with `includes` and `excludes`) ([see this open issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21312))

Your query can be rewritten like this and it will work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "gone"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "timedTextLines",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "timedTextLines.textLine": "damn"
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {
             "_source": {
                "includes":[
                  "timedTextLines.startTime",
                  "timedTextLines.endTime"
                ]
             },
              "highlight": {
                "fields": {
                  "timedTextLines.textLine": {

                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source":"false"
}
```

Comment: This answer made me realize I was missing the starting <path> portion before each field I wanted to include (e.g. "timedTextLines." in your example). FYI for anyone who sees this, make sure you include the full nested path to your field for _source to work correctly.